# Numpy switch specific section of column with same section in another column

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array A:

```
>>> A=np.array([[1,2,3],
                [1,3,0],
                [2,0,0]])
```

that I want to get to:

```
>>> B
     array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.],
            [ 2.,  0.,  0.],
            [ 3.,  0.,  0.],
            [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
            [ 0.,  3.,  0.],
            [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
            [ 0.,  0.,  2.],
            [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
            [ 0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

I am currently doing this by:

```
>>> rows,cols=A.shape

>>> C=np.zeros([rows*cols,cols])

>>> C[:,0]=np.ravel(A)

>>> for i in range(1,C.shape[1]):
...     C[i*rows:(i+1)*rows,[i,0]]=C[i*rows:(i+1)*rows,[0,i]]
```

Is there a way to do this transformation without a loop?

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> rows, cols = A.shape
>>> row_idx = np.arange(rows*cols)
>>> col_idx = np.repeat(np.arange(rows), cols)
>>> B = np.zeros((rows*cols, rows), dtype=A.dtype)
>>> B[row_idx, col_idx] = A.ravel()
>>> B
array([[1, 0, 0],
       [2, 0, 0],
       [3, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [0, 3, 0],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 2],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0]])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
rows = A.shape[0]
C = np.zeros((A.size, rows))
ind = np.arange(0, C.size, rows).reshape(A.shape) + np.arange(rows)[:,None]
C.flat[ind] = A
```